# Manual simulation of Markov Chain in R

Tags: r, simulation, markov-process

> Consider the Markov chain with state space *S = {1, 2}*, transition matrix
>
> [image]
>
> and initial distribution *α = (1/2, 1/2)*.
>
> 1. Simulate 5 steps of the Markov chain (that is, simulate *X<sub>0</sub>*, *X<sub>1</sub>*, . . . , *X<sub>5</sub>*). Repeat the simulation 100
>      times. Use the results of your simulations to solve the following problems.
>
>    - Estimate *P(X<sub>1</sub> = 1|X<sub>0</sub> = 1)*. Compare your result with the exact probability.

My solution:

```
# returns Xn 
func2 <- function(alpha1, mat1, n1) 
{
  xn <- alpha1 %*% matrixpower(mat1, n1+1)

  return (xn)
}

alpha <- c(0.5, 0.5)
mat <- matrix(c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1), nrow=2, ncol=2)
n <- 10


for (variable in 1:100) 
{
   print(func2(alpha, mat, n))
}
```

What is the difference if I run this code once versus 100 times (as is said in the problem-statement)?

How can I find the conditional probability from here on?

Answer (score 2):

The R function `func2` produces the vector$$(\alpha,1-\alpha) \mathbf P^n$$which is the marginal distribution of the Markov chain after $n$ steps, given that the initial state is generated with distribution $(\alpha,1-\alpha)$. To *generate* the Markov chain, one needs to proceed one step at a time:

1. generate $X_0$ equal to $1$ with probability $\alpha$ and $2$ with probability $1-\alpha$
2. generate $X_1$ which is equal to $2$ if $X_0=2$  and to $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $2$ with probability $1/2$ if $X_0=1$
3. generate $X_2$ which is equal to $2$ if $X_1=2$  and to $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $2$ with probability $1/2$ if $X_1=1$
4. generate $X_3$ which is equal to $2$ if $X_2=2$  and to $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $2$ with probability $1/2$ if $X_2=1$
5. generate $X_4$ which is equal to $2$ if $X_3=2$  and to $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $2$ with probability $1/2$ if $X_3=1$
6. generate $X_5$ which is equal to $2$ if $X_4=2$  and to $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $2$ with probability $1/2$ if $X_4=1$

Each transition can be simulated by a one-line code such as

```
tranz <- function(x=1) 2-(x==1)*(runif(1)<.5)
```

leading to a five step Markov chain in a similarly easy coding such as

```
marx <- function(alf=.5){ 
   x=2-(runif(1)<alf)
   for (t in 2:6) x=c(x,tranz(x[t-1]))
   return(x)}
```

Thus one recovers one *realisation* of the sequence $X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5$. Rerunning the algorithm 99 times produces in total 100 *realisations* of the sequence $X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5$. Not necessarily all different (actually certainly not all different!), but iid replicas of such realisations, from which $\mathbb P(X_1 = 1|X_0 = 1)$ and $\mathbb P(X_5 = 1|X_0 = 1)$ can be estimated by the Law of Large Numbers.

Here is an illustration for 100 replications when $\alpha=.7$:

[image]

where the 6x100 values have been jittered and the curve corresponds to the 6 means of the simulated $X_t$'s.

Comment: I think your sentences from 1 to 6, need some punctuation. Otherwise, I am lost.